# Clear mac os power query cache

Tags: excel, odata, powerquery

I am trying to use excel power query on mac os but I am having trouble. I want to make an odata request, I have a local server which is not running.

When I create a Query

OData.Feed("http://localhost:8080/MyPath", null, [Implementation = "2.0"])

It keeps returning values even if my server is not running

I tried to remove ~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Caches/ files and directories, restart my computer and nothing changes.

How can I remove the excel or power query cache ?

I also tried to remove

~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Excel/Data/Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Office/16.0/Wef/

~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Office365ServiceV2/Data/Caches/com.microsoft.Office365ServiceV2/

~/Library/Containers/com.microsoft.Office365ServiceV2/Data/Library/Caches/com.microsoft.Office365ServiceV2/

but I don't have these directories ...

Comment: Have you figured it out? I'm also interested about the solution, Excel for Mac OS is not very well documented, unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry I give up, maybe try while turning off internet, if they stored something in the microshit cloud

Comment: Hi Alays,
I already contacted the O365 support and the official statement is that there is no feature in Office for Mac to clear the cache and no public workaround.
My workaround is appending an arbitrary query string to the url which leads to a different URI, so avoiding using the cache.